# There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first linq

Tags: c#, linq, datareader

Where the error in the following code? 
There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command the which must be closed first.

"An error Occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details."

```
var cat = from c in db.Question select c;
foreach (Questions question in cat) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", question.tittle);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", question.deskripsi);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", question.id_question);
    **foreach (Categories p in question.Categories)**
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", p.id_kategori);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", p.nama_kategori);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this Linq-to-SQL or Linq-to-Entities?

Answer (score 8):

You probably didn't enable *multiple active result sets* (MARS) in your config file. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are some details of why and how, but it always entails adding an entry

```
"MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

to the connection string.

However, apart from activating MARS, it's better to eager load the `Categories`:

```
from c in db.Question.Include(q => q.Categories) select c
```

because in your code each iteration of the `foreach` will execute a query to lazy load the categories (also known as *n + 1 problem*).

Comment: when i change, the error "Could not find the conceptual model type for 'MyStuck.Models.Category'." FYI(i am create the model manually)

Comment: OK, the exception of your question is solved. Now you've got a new question.